# swfobject with html-class?

Tags: css, flash, class, swfobject

hey guys,
is there any parameter where i could apply a classname to a swfobject?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/j_aFmziaRdU&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer_13", "ytplayer_13", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params);

    </script>
```

This gets rendered as `<object ...`
Is there any chance where i could add a classname to this `<object` when creating it with swfobject? like `<object class="classnam" ...`

Comment: Made your code visible (use `` s to mask the `<>` in xml) and added a css tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [attributes parameter](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) (there is no direct link to the paragraph, open link and search for "STEP 3: Embed your SWF with JavaScript" headline) to assign an id or a class to the object.  You could then use `document.getElementById()` to get the object, once it has been created.  Or use `#id` or `.classname` from CSS, just the way you would expect it to work.  Caution, though: `attributes.class` would cause an error (it's a reserved keyword), you have to use `attributes.styleclass` to set the classname.

Comment: yeah thank you. I'm already adding it with jquery. That works fine. I was just wondering if there is a better way so i don't have to wait for the object to be created.

Comment: You don't, if you use css selectors - the browser will handle it for you.

Comment: what do you mean by css-selectors? what do you mean with "you don't"? I'm just looking for the best way to add a classname to this <swfobject> now i'm simply using jquery with $('#vidoeID').addClass('classname'); and that works fine. Is there a better and faster (or more reliable) way of doing this or not?

Comment: I meant: If you use the argument parameter, you don't have to wait for the object to exist.  Use `attributes.styleclass="classname"` and add the attributes object to your `swfobject.embedSWF()` call, as described in the documentation I linked to.  A CSS selector is the expression used to select the element directly from a stylesheet (`.classname`, in your case), as opposed to selecting the element via JavaScript.

Comment: thanks, i know what a CSS selector is. I just have no idea how and where i use this attributes.styleclass thingy? Do I have to use this .registerObject() Method? I'm sorry but I'm not that much of a coder.

Comment: No, you just have to read that damn documentation! ;)  It's really simple: `var attributes = {}; attributes.styleclass="classname"; swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/
j_aFmziaRdU&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer_13", 
"ytplayer_13", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params, attributes);`

Comment: amazing! thank you very much. wouldn't have found it anyway! :) thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

You can alter you swfobject.js file, and manually add it there.  Or do a manual embed, versus SWFObject.  Also, typically SWFObject is inserted into a container div, you should also be able to insert a class there.

Hope this helps. I think that's what you were asking, if not, my bad.

Comment: -1 because this is really not a helpful answer at all: It serves only one use-case (what if you had a website with many Flash objects and different style classes - would you create an individual swfobject.js for each one?), and it creates the impression that SWFObject can only be used in a very crude and unpractical way, creating stiff and unflexible HTML, which is exactly the problem it was meant to fix.

Comment: Moreover, swfobject *replaces* the container div with the flash object, so adding a class there does exactly nothing.

Comment: -1 for answering his question?  Just because you consider it a crude answer, it still serves the purpose.  Your answer is the better one, and it was there when I posted mine. I was providing an alternative.  Just because *you* wouldn't use it, doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't make it right, either. I didn't give you -1 because you answered the question.  I gave you -1, because it a) the answer isn't correct (the `<div>`part) and b) it isn't helpful (the rest, see explanation above).  And obviously, someone else must have felt the same way about it, too.